# How can I change the font size in the title area of the Navigation bar in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

The font that I have is too big for the amount of words that I would like to display. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can change the font size. I would prefer to be able to do it in the shared code but if it needs a custom renderer then can someone show me how this can be done?

Comment: What version of Xamarin.Form are you using?

Answer (score 8):

So, if you are using Xamarin.Forms 3.2.0 or above, you can use `TitleView` property like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Xamarin.Forms.Controls.GalleryPages.TitleView">

    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <Label Text="This is my Title" FontSize="12" TextColor="White" />
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <!-- YOUR CONTENT HERE-->
</ContentPage>
```